# How does sleeping routine effect game performance?

Tags: sleep

Here is a case that I ran into in one of the professional basketball teams. Athletes train both in the morning and late afternoon and they must sleep between 1:00pm and 3:00pm during the weekdays except Friday because they have games on Friday at 2:00pm. What I wonder is that since the body and metabolism are accustomed to sleep between the above mentioned hours during the weekdays, how these sleeping routine effect game performance.

In short: does napping from 1pm-3pm on Monday to Thursday affects game performance on Friday at 2pm?

PS. These practice and sleeping hours are mandatory so they cannot be changed.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are actually asking, your title says a simple question but the text below talks about metabolism, could you/anyone else reword your detail to make a bit more sense?

Comment: What I mean they sleep during noon and they have game at noon once a week. How this effect game performance. I hope this helps. You can skip metabolism part in your answer.

Comment: Doesn't this answer you give basically answer your question? http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29054/do-we-need-contiguous-sleep-for-gains

Comment: I think It does not :-(

Comment: @JJosaur From what I understand, he wants to know if napping from 1pm-3pm on Monday to Thursday affects game performance on Friday at 2pm. The rest is just padding.

Comment: The question to ask is: why are they napping from 1 to 30 pm, first of all?

Comment: te get rest basically

Comment: This is all? Is there any real practical reason why they nap in terms of periodization of training regimen?

Comment: I do not know the exact reason why they sleep. I believe that the trainer want them to sleep but this is not the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not create any problem.

Such short resting periods do not create an adaptation worth of notice in ones circadian rythm.

On top of that, what you want to take in account here is neural function and **reactivity** of CNS.

When they have the game they dont sleep, so the problem its not there. If they were sleeping also before the game, and for such a long time, then it could be problematic to switch from a low activation profile to a high activation profile ( depending on **sympathetic nervous system** activation ).
In this case you could have a decrease in performance not fitness-wise, but mental-wise ( attention performance ).

Generally **power napping** is used ( but includes briefer times of sleep, at most 15'-20' ) to enhance attention for a certain period of time just after you wake up. This is not the case however.

Answer is: no problem.